# Can't read from my .txt file

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read from a textfile with the `Scanner` class, but it's not working as I want to.
Simple code as this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {        
    
    File f = new File("D://Blandat/Test.txt");            
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    
    System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
    
}
```

The output becomes `false` even though I have 3 lines of text.

> Hello World!
>
> the best is yet to come
>
> This is the third line with text, with a blank line between.

So even with

```
sc.hastNext()
```

I should at least get an output of Hello, but I just recieve nothing.
I have used other classes like `FileInputStream, InputStreamReader, BufferedReader` and the all worked just fine with the same path,text and everything.

Comment: Is your file open?

File f = new File("D://Blandat/Test.txt");            
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
String line = sc.next(); //what does this return?

Comment: @Paul It only returns a `false` value back

Answer (score 0):

Have a go at wrapping in a try catch. See if you can spot any exceptions. Open in Programmers notepad see if there's any weird BOM markers or anything. Also, double check your imports, make sure you haven't autocompleted the wrong scanner class. Should be java.util.Scanner; I think.

```
try {
    File f = new File("D://Blandat//Test.txt");   
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.next();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    sc.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that my class throws those exceptions that comes from scanner class.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why but after I manually changed some text in the file, and I compiled my code, with worked like a charm. I even went back and used the same text I had when I recieved the "error" after, and even that worked..I am so done.